# C# find 2D small array in 2d big array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
    int[,] data = new int[,] {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    };
    int[,] find = new int[,] {
        { 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1 }
    };

    bool result = Check2DArray (data, find);
```

How do I search for a small 2D array in a large 2D array?

Comment: There's no silver bullet for that task. Just code two for loops and you're done.

Comment: If one goes and matches, it matches the bottom lines but I can not

Comment: @gdir More like 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this snippet :

```
static bool Check2DArray(int[,] data, int[,] find)
{
    int dataLen = data.Length; // length of the whole data
    int findLen = find.Length; // length of the whole find

    for(int i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) // iterate through data
    {
        int dataX = i % data.GetLength(0); // get current column index
        int dataY = i / data.GetLength(0); // get current row index

        bool okay = true; // declare result placeholder for that check
        for (int j = 0; j < findLen && okay; j++) // iterate through find
        {
            int findX = j % find.GetLength(1); // current column in find
            int findY = j / find.GetLength(1); // current row in find

            int checkedX = findX + dataX; // column index in data to check
            int checkedY = findY + dataY; // row index in data to check

            // check if checked index is not going outside of the data boundries 
            if ( checkedX >= data.GetLength(0) || checkedY >= data.GetLength(1))
            {
                // we are outside of the data boundries
                // set flag to false and break checks for this data row and column
                okay = false;
                break; 
            }

            // we are still inside of the data boundries so check if values matches
            okay = data[dataY + findY, dataX + findX] == find[findY, findX]; // check if it matches
        }
        if(okay) // if all values from both fragments are equal
            return true; // return true

    }
    return false;
}
```

You can check that [online here](http://rextester.com/UOFQ25170)

Please give me some feedback and if it is not clear enough I can explain in more details :)

**EDIT :**
Found an issue that this method was not checking last row and column in the `data` argument. Now after small fix all works perfectly.

**EDIT2 :**
Thanks to [@SefaTunçkanat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3709087/sefatun%c3%a7kanat) for pointing out my mistake. There was an issue with some calculations which could lead to `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions and comparing wrong inputs. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Nice compiler, thanks for the answer and comment lines

Comment: But when I multiply the search value I get an error 
`int[,] data = new int[,] {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            };
            int[,] find = new int[,] {
                { 0,1 },
                { 1,1 },
                { 0,1 },
                { 0,1 }
            };`

Comment: @SefaTunçkanat Yes there was a mistake from my side. Check edited answer. Also edited link to the online check with values you've posted in comment

Comment: @SefaTunçkanat It took longer then expected, but should work fine now. Again thank you very much for finding me and pointing my mistake out.

Answer (score 2):

Make a helper method that checks if a big array contains a small array starting at the given position `(row, col)`. Make two nested loops to iterate over all `(row, col)` pairs in the big array where the small array could fit, and see if any pair would produce a match.

```
static bool EqualAtPosition(int[,] big, int[,] small, int row, int col) {
    var rowCount = small.GetLength(0);
    var colCount = small.GetLength(1);
    if (row+rowCount > big.GetLength(0) || col+colCount > big.GetLength(1)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var r = 0 ; r != rowCount ; r++) {
        for (var c = 0 ; c != colCount ; c++) {
            if (big[row+r, col+c] != small[r, c]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does column and row mean? 2 dimensional arrays are not enough for operation?

Comment: @SefaTunçkanat `EqualAtPosition` checks for match at one position. You call this method from two nested loops, on row and column, to find the position of overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just loop through all "start" positions that the smaller array could fit in the bigger one, then loop through the values of the smaller array and compare to the relative position in the bigger, if there isn't a match you need to continue to the next position in the bigger array, or if all match you can return `true`, if you finish going through the bigger array without finding a match then you return `false`.

```
public static bool Check2DArray(int[,] data, int[,] find)
{
    for (int dRow = 0; dRow < data.GetLength(0) - find.GetLength(0); dRow++)
    {
        for (int dCol = 0; dCol < data.GetLength(1) - find.GetLength(1); dCol++)
        {
            bool found = true;

            for (int fRow = 0; fRow < find.GetLength(0); fRow++)
            {
                for (int fCol = 0; fCol < find.GetLength(1); fCol++)
                {
                    if (data[dRow + fRow, dCol + fCol] != find[fRow,fCol])
                    {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found) break;
            }

            if (found) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also you could use @dasblinkenlight's solution to replace the inner two loops if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the arrays and your requirements a simple brute-force algorithm may suffice.

You would start at [0,0] in your big array and check if all the items from this coordinate on are equal to the items in the small array.
If they are you have found a match. If not you would go to the next position in the big array.

Answer (score 1):

1. take the first element of the small array at [0,0] (let's call it `start_e`)
2. run with 2 for-loops through the big array
3. if you find `start_e` copy the sub array from the big one of the size of the small one and
4. compare it with a helping method that can check 2 Arrays of same size.